# how to determine WiFi signal in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

iPhone can determine WiFi station in network?

And also MAC address for that WiFi station i want to retrieve.

So can u help me?

Comment: Isn't this the same question you asked here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686100/get-remote-mac-address-of-wifi-station-in-iphone ?

Answer (score 1):

try looking at the [Reachability](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/Reachability/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324) example application on Apple's Developer Center.

Comment: programatically how can i get my nearest WiFi station's MAC address?