# Get WAP MAC on iPhone/ObjC?

Tags: iphone

What call can I use to get the MAC address of the WAP I'm currently connected to on the iPhone?

Comment: This is a duplicate of these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686100/get-remote-mac-address-of-wifi-station-in-iphone , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/689056/how-to-determine-wifi-signal-in-iphone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, one does it the same way as in Mac OS/X. You need to look in the ARP tables built by the OS as it talks to remote hosts/bridges.

I'm not sure you'll find a ready-made library, but the standard C way should work.

I found [ArpSpy](http://thebends.org/~allen/arpspyx/) which has downloadable source, and should serve as an example. It uses libpcap to sniff packets; I'm not sure if this has been ported and/or is usable on the iPhone.